# Python search for string in csv columns and write row in another csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, row, case-insensitive

I'm fairly new to coding but I was trying to write a code that reads over a csv file to check if strings that the user inputs are in specific columns and then writes out the row in which the strings are present in a separate csv file. The issue is that when I run the code, it only prints out 1 row rather than multiple rows that have the strings within them. I also tried to make it case insensitive but somehow it doesn't work either.

My code right now looks like this:

```
import csv
shape = input("Type in a shape ")
color = input("Type in a color")
with open("directory.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csvreader:
      if shape.lower() in row[7] and color.lower() in row[6] :
         with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator = "\n")
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Any help or suggestions are very much needed!

Answer (score 0):

pandas is here to help you. use the fragment below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("directory.csv")
df1 = df[df["column1"] == shape & df["column2"] == color]
df1.to_csv("found_data.csv")
```

Comment: An alternative to using .str.contains is df1 = df[df["column1"] == shape & df["column2"] == color]. This will get an exact match rather than just words that contain the string.

Comment: Added the changes @HenryCWong

Answer (score 0):

`data.csv` is truncated every time it's opened in `'w'` mode, so it will only contain the final match.  Moving the `open` statement to the beginning of the code fixes the problem.

```
import csv
shape = input("Type in a shape ")
color = input("Type in a color")
with open("directory.csv", "r") as f, open("data.csv", "w") as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if shape.lower() in row[7] and color.lower() in row[6] :
            writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator = "\n")
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Alternatively, the file could be opened in `'a'` (append) mode, and then existing lines in the file will be preserved:

```
import csv
shape = input("Type in a shape ")
color = input("Type in a color")
with open("directory.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csvreader:
      if shape.lower() in row[7] and color.lower() in row[6] :
         with open("data.csv", "a") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator = "\n")
            writer.writerow(row)
```